# Finding Max of Max mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I am using a table called covid_vaccinations.

To briefly explain about the table, it tracks down all the countries' vaccination completion by every single day from Feb xx, 2020 to Jan XX, 2022.

- The name of the countries are called 'location' in this table.
- The countries (location) are also categorized in the column of 'continent'

To find the people who are fully vaccinated in Asia, I used the query below:

```
SELECT continent,location, MAX(people_fully_vaccinated)
FROM covid_vaccinations
WHERE continent LIKE '%ASIA%'
GROUP BY continent, location
ORDER BY 3 DESC;
```

I used MAX() since the <people_fully_vaccinated> column includes the cumulative number of data.

The query above gave me the result I wanted, see  [<image 1>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L7EB0.png)

HERE IS MY QUESTION:

If I just want to get the GREATEST result of people_fully_vaccinated, how should I write the query?
I tried below, and it gave me the same result as <image 1>

```
SELECT location, MAX(peep_f_vacc_asia)
FROM (
     SELECT location, MAX(people_fully_vaccinated) as peep_f_vacc_asia
     FROM covid_vaccinations
     WHERE continent LIKE '%ASIA%'
     GROUP BY continent,location
     ) A
GROUP BY location
ORDER BY 2 DESC;
```

The desired result I want to see would be only a single row, China (which has the greatest number of people_fully_vaccinated)

Thank you so much guys...

Comment: after your order  by you can add `limit 1` that will show you only 1 record

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be able to get away with just using a `LIMIT` query.  A slight modification of your first query:

```sql
SELECT continent, location, MAX(people_fully_vaccinated)
FROM covid_vaccinations
WHERE continent LIKE '%ASIA%'
GROUP BY continent, location
ORDER BY 3 DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

But this only works in the case that there are no ties for a given continent and location for the max number of fully vaccinated.  If you do have to worry about ties, and you are using MySQL 8+, then we can use `RANK` as follows:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT continent, location, MAX(people_fully_vaccinated) AS max_fv,
           RANK() OVER (ORDER BY MAX(people_fully_vaccinated) DESC) rnk
    FROM covid_vaccinations
    WHERE continent LIKE '%ASIA%'
    GROUP BY continent, location
)

SELECT continent, location, max_fv
FROM cte
WHERE rnk = 1;
```